# The diagram for the many to many relationship table does not appear in the edmx

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework, edmx

I am using a databse first method. I generated edmx from the database. But diagrams for the tables which are in many to many relationships do not display in the generated edmx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Many to many lookup table consists of just Foreign Keys and no other fields, then it will not show up in your edmx file as a Table. It will show up under Navigation Properties of each table though.